# Align the width of the UL with that of the input (filter)

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a filter search. When the user types, the results will appear in a UL below the search. The UL (where it shows the filter results) is not aligned with the input. Here is an image to have an idea:

[image]

Any idea?

And another question: the results at UL are not showing up in IE. How to solve?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/marcelpsaraiva/p40vxdmL/

```js
   var jsonData = {
        "squadName": "Super hero squad",
        "homeTown": "Metro City",
        "formed": 2016,
        "secretBase": "Super tower",
        "active": true,
        "members": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Molecule Man",
            "age": 29,
            "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
            "powers": [
              "Radiation resistance",
              "Turning tiny",
              "Radiation blast"
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Madame Uppercut",
            "age": 39,
            "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
            "powers": [
              "Million tonne punch",
              "Damage resistance",
              "Superhuman reflexes"
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Eternal Flame",
            "age": 1000000,
            "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
            "powers": [
              "Immortality",
              "Heat Immunity",
              "Inferno",
              "Teleportation",
              "Interdimensional travel"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }


      montaComponente(jsonData['members']);


   document.querySelector("#search_json").addEventListener('blur', function() {
         
        let opcoesLi = document.querySelectorAll('.opcao');

        esconderOpcoes(opcoesLi);
      });


   document.querySelector("#search_json").addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      
         let texto_filtro = document.getElementById("search_json").value.toLowerCase();
         let lista_elem = [...document.querySelectorAll('.opcao')];
         let opcoesLi = document.querySelectorAll('.opcao');

         let filtrado = (filt) => {

            if(filt.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(texto_filtro) === true){
              document.getElementById(filt['id']).style.display = "block";
            }else {
              document.getElementById(filt['id']).style.display = "none";
            }

          }

          if(texto_filtro.trim() != '') {
            let arrayFiltrado = lista_elem.filter(filtrado);
          }else{
            esconderOpcoes(opcoesLi);
          }
   });


      function montaComponente(jsonDados) {

        var selecao = document.querySelector("#lista-opcoes");

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonDados.length; i++) {

          var opt = montaLi(jsonDados[i]['id'], jsonDados[i]['name']);

          selecao.appendChild(opt);
        }
        
      }


      function montaLi(id_dado, texto_dado) {
        var opt = document.createElement("li");
        var link = document.createElement("a");

        opt.classList.add("opcao");
        opt.setAttribute('id', 'opcao_'+id_dado);
        opt.style.display = 'none';
        
        link.textContent = texto_dado;

        opt.appendChild(link);

        return opt;
      }


      function esconderOpcoes(opcoes) {

        for (var i = 0; i < opcoes.length; i++) {
          if(opcoes[i].style.display == 'block') {
            opcoes[i].style.display = 'none';
          }
        }

      }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

      #search_json {
        float: right;
        background-image: url('iconfinder_icon-111-search_314478.png');
        background-position: 10px 12px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
      }

      #search_json:focus {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .zerar-espaco {
        clear: both;
      }

      #lista-opcoes {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        /*margin: 0;*/
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 27px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        width:100%;
      }

      #lista-opcoes li a {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        padding: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: black;
        display: block;
      }

      #lista-opcoes li a:hover:not(.header) {
        background-color: #eee;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Filtro</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h3>Filtro</h3>

  <form>
   <input id="search_json" type="text" name="" placeholder="Pesquisar.."><br>
      <ul id="lista-opcoes"></ul>
  </form>

    <div class="zerar-espaco"></div>

    <p>testando texto</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet right **here**, not on any external code site.

Comment: I delete js code here. All code is here:  https://jsfiddle.net/marcelpsaraiva/p40vxdmL/

Comment: Again: **Please create a runnable snippet right here, not on any external code site.** To do that, click *edit* below your post, then click the `<>` icon.

Comment: Sorry @connexo. Now I understand and fixed the post! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `flexbox` to do it:

```js
var jsonData = {
        "squadName": "Super hero squad",
        "homeTown": "Metro City",
        "formed": 2016,
        "secretBase": "Super tower",
        "active": true,
        "members": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Molecule Man",
            "age": 29,
            "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
            "powers": [
              "Radiation resistance",
              "Turning tiny",
              "Radiation blast"
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Madame Uppercut",
            "age": 39,
            "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
            "powers": [
              "Million tonne punch",
              "Damage resistance",
              "Superhuman reflexes"
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Eternal Flame",
            "age": 1000000,
            "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
            "powers": [
              "Immortality",
              "Heat Immunity",
              "Inferno",
              "Teleportation",
              "Interdimensional travel"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }


      montaComponente(jsonData['members']);


   document.querySelector("#search_json").addEventListener('blur', function() {
         
        let opcoesLi = document.querySelectorAll('.opcao');

        esconderOpcoes(opcoesLi);
      });


   document.querySelector("#search_json").addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      
         let texto_filtro = document.getElementById("search_json").value.toLowerCase();
         let lista_elem = [...document.querySelectorAll('.opcao')];
         let opcoesLi = document.querySelectorAll('.opcao');

         let filtrado = (filt) => {

            if(filt.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(texto_filtro) === true){
              document.getElementById(filt['id']).style.display = "block";
            }else {
              document.getElementById(filt['id']).style.display = "none";
            }

          }

          if(texto_filtro.trim() != '') {
            let arrayFiltrado = lista_elem.filter(filtrado);
          }else{
            esconderOpcoes(opcoesLi);
          }
   });


      function montaComponente(jsonDados) {

        var selecao = document.querySelector("#lista-opcoes");

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonDados.length; i++) {

          var opt = montaLi(jsonDados[i]['id'], jsonDados[i]['name']);

          selecao.appendChild(opt);
        }
        
      }


      function montaLi(id_dado, texto_dado) {
        var opt = document.createElement("li");
        var link = document.createElement("a");

        opt.classList.add("opcao");
        opt.setAttribute('id', 'opcao_'+id_dado);
        opt.style.display = 'none';
        
        link.textContent = texto_dado;

        opt.appendChild(link);

        return opt;
      }


      function esconderOpcoes(opcoes) {

        for (var i = 0; i < opcoes.length; i++) {
          if(opcoes[i].style.display == 'block') {
            opcoes[i].style.display = 'none';
          }
        }

      }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-end;
position: relative;
}
      #search_json {
        float: right;
        background-image: url('iconfinder_icon-111-search_314478.png');
        background-position: 10px 12px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
      }

      #search_json:focus {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .zerar-espaco {
        clear: both;
      }

      #lista-opcoes {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 45px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }

      #lista-opcoes li a {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        padding: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: black;
        display: block;
      }

      #lista-opcoes li a:hover:not(.header) {
        background-color: #eee;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Filtro</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h3>Filtro</h3>

  <form class="form-container">
   <input id="search_json" type="text" name="" placeholder="Pesquisar..">
      <ul id="lista-opcoes"></ul>
  </form>

    <div class="zerar-espaco"></div>

    <p>testando texto</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, in part its works, but I want the UL is front of the text (below, p tag). So I have to use position absolute.